# how to install mpfun90?

Tags: fortran, multiprecision

I am trying to write a multiprecision program in Fortran. I already wrote a double precision program in Fortran. Can anybody help me to convert it to multiprecision. I discovered D. Baily multiprecision Library (  http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/    for mpfun90) but I was unable to install it. How can I install MPFUN90 on Ubuntu? Can Someone help me with it (step by step)? I use  gfortran compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Download.  ungzip and untar.  Then use:
`gfortran mpfun90.f90  mpmod90.f90 YourProg.f90 -o YourProg.exe`